# postgresql: select returning ARRAY

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table as:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_temp (id serial, friend_id int, name varchar(32));
```

I wish I could run the following SQL:

```
PREPARE x AS SELECT {$1,friend_id} FROM tbl_temp WHERE id = ANY($2);  
EXECUTE x(33, ARRAY[1,2,3,4])
```

I basically looking for a statement that will return me an array of two ints first of which will be user input and second will be from table column like `friend_id`.

Is it really possible in PostgreSQL?

The results from SELECT ($1, friend_id) FROM tbl_temp;

```
EXECUTE x(44);
  row     
--------  
 (44,1)  
 (44,2)  
 (44,3)  
(3 rows)
```

If I use `PQgetvalue(PGres, 0, 0)` how will the result look like: `{44,45}` or like `(44,45)`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you want to use the [array constructor syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS):

```
SELECT ARRAY[$1, friend_id] FROM tbl_temp WHERE id = ANY($2)
```

Answer (score 4):

i'm not sure i understand what you want...

to return an array, do this.

```
SELECT (44, "friend_id") FROM "tbl_temp" WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I actually was looking for something like `SELECT ARRAY[$1, friend_id] FROM tbl_temp WHERE id = ANY($2)
`... Got it from _mu is too short_